# Scala - Implementing a polymorphic abstract trait without polymorphism

Tags: scala, functional-programming, polymorphism

I'm designing a simple data-processing pipeline in Scala. It involves `PipelineStage`'s, which `transform` some `StageOutput` into another `StageOutput`. A `Pipeline` is a wrapper for a sequence of `PipelineStage`'s which needs to generically access all of their `transform` methods.

However I'm having trouble as both solutions I've come up with fundamentally don't work... the first relies on an abstract polymorphic method being implemented in a non-polymorphic way (doesn't compile) and the second relies on being able to use a `Seq[AbstractTrait]` where the `AbstractTrait` is polymorphic, which is again meaningless to the compiler. See as follows...

Scenario 1. Make the `transform` method polymorphic.

```
    abstract trait PipelineStage {
        def transform[A <: StageOutput, B <: StageOutput](in: A): B
    }

    class PipelineStage2 extends PipelineStage {
        def transform(in: StageOutput1): StageOutput2
    }

    class Pipeline {
        def stages: Seq[PipelineStage]
    }
```

Here the `Pipeline` has no trouble compiling, but the stages won't compile since the signatures of their `transform` methods, whilst they 'respect' the abstract signature's polymorphism, aren't actually polymorphic themselves so don't match up as far as the compiler is concerned.

Scenario 2. Make the `PipelineStage` trait itself polymorphic.

```
    abstract trait PipelineStage[A <: StageOutput, B <: StageOutput] {
        def transform(in: A): B
    }

    class PipelineStage2 extends PipelineStage[StageOutput1, StageOutput2] {
        def transform(in: StageOutput1): StageOutput2
    }

    class Pipeline {
        def stages: Seq[PipelineStage]
    }
```

This solves the problem for the `PipelineStage`s, they have no trouble compiling, and their transform methods work fine on their own. However, they don't technically implement the same trait now, so `Pipeline` doesn't compile since `Seq[PipelineStage]` is meaningless now...

Is there an established pattern for either implementing polymorphic abstract methods without the polymorphism, or referencing a sequence of classes implementing the same abstract polymorphic trait? My feeling is no and that I've probably approached this in the wrong way, but perhaps there's a syntactical trick I'm missing somewhere along the line. Thanks.

Comment: Try filling in the body of the `Pipeline` method assuming that you got it to compile in some way, and have access to `def stages: Seq[PipelineStage]`. 
Show how exactly you are planning to use that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one doesn't do what you want at all: `StageOutput1` and `2` in `def transform[StageOutput1, StageOutput2](in: StageOutput1): StageOutput2` are just parameter names, it means exactly the same as `def transform[A, B](in: A): B`.

My suggestion would be to use the second, but instead of `class Pipeline` you can add

```
def compose[C <: StageOutput](other: PipelineStage[B, C]): PipelineStage[A, C] = new PipelineStage[A, C] {
  def transform(in: A) = other.transform(PipelineStage.this.transform(in))
}
```

and build up the pipeline you want, provided the types actually match.

(Also, your `PipelineStage` is basically a `Function1` with a constraint; if you don't plan to add other methods, or to intentionally limit the kinds of stages that can be written, you may want to just use functions and take advantage of the standard library!)

Comment: You're absolutely right, edited to remove the polymorphism in the first scenario's `PipelineStage1`'s `transform` method. Was a typo and not what I had tried to compile.

Also, I do have a several other methods and attribute on a `PipelineStage` so I do need to use a trait.
However, I didn't really think about the fact that there's nothing fundamentally different between a `PipelineStage` and a `Pipeline`. I can put all the methods I wanted on `Pipeline` on `PipelineStage` and use your compose function. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest calling it `Pipeline` instead of `PipelineStage`.